# Nginx says 404 not found, no error log

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, fedora

I am getting a 404 not found at nginx page, i get no error in nginx error log file too.

```
server {
    listen 6269;
    server_name  (domain);
    root  /home/temp;
    index /_h5ai/public/index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex  on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        autoindex_localtime on;
     }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    } 
}
```

- error.log is empty
- access .log has:

`X.0.X.190 - - [17/Nov/2018:21:50:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36" "-"`

- OS: Fedora 29

Comment: Hi, does your client request hit the correct web server ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I this so.. Using IP:6269 for accessing and no other server is listening to it, this is the only block except the default one

Answer (score 7):

nginx uses `error` as the default log level for `error_log`. This logging level does not output anything to the error log in case of 404 responses, since those are trivial errors in the scope of web server operation.

You can try changing the log level by using either `warn`, `notice`, `info` or `debug` in your `error_log` directive, for example:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
```

`warn` outputs a bit more information than `error`, `notice` a bit more than `warn`. `debug` produces most detailed output.

With your configuration, you need to have the following file for the `GET /` request to work:

```
/home/temp/_h5ai/public/index.php
```

Comment: good answer, but you did not clarify which exact level logs the 404 error

Comment: For those wondering: `debug` gives you enough detail that you can, with some scrolling, eventually identify a 404. But it doesn't raise the 404s as it's own log entry... rather it logs, in detail, every request, including all the routing that went into it, eventually leading to the conclusion that the response will need to be a 404.